# Can I have a non-empty hashmap with no keys in it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dictionary, hashmap, key

I had a weird and unexpected behaviour on a java HashMap, on a part of code that is solely for testing.

To try and set a unique ID to an object before storing it in session I use a `if{}else{}` statement but I found myself with an error in my app.

The ID is generated for test purposes as there is currently no database to actually store the data, which is stored in session in the meantime.

Here's my snippet of code:

```
 ...
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 Map<Integer, Booking> bookings = (HashMap<Integer, Booking>) session.getAttribute(SESSION_BOOKINGS);

 // Generates ID
 if (bookings == null)
 {
      bookings= new HashMap<Integer, Booking>();
      identificator = 1;
 }
 else
 {
      Object[] arrayKeys = (Object[]) bookings.keySet().toArray();
      Arrays.sort(arrayKeys);
      identificator = (Integer) arrayKeys[arrayKeys.length - 1] + 1;
 }

 ...
 //... The rest is setting the ID to the current worked on booking,
 //... putting the ID/booking pair in the bookings map
 //... and storing the map in session, which worked fine
```

The error came up after deleting a booking in the map when the map contained only one. When I tried to register one more after that, I got an error with the following error cause `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` and the trace linked to the last line of my `else` statement: `identificator = (Integer) arrayKeys[arrayKeys.length - 1] + 1;`

So:

1. `arrayKeys.length -1 == -1 // true`
2. which means that `arrayKeys.length == 0 // true`
3. which in turns mean that the `keySet()` from `Map<Integer,Booking> bookings` is empty
4. yet the test does not enter the `if` statement

On the other hand, on a brand new session (after either restarting the browser or logging out and in again), the test did enter the if statement as expected.

After testing I changed my condition from `(bookings==null)`
to `(bookings==null || bookings.isEmpty())`.
Further testing showed that using only `(bookings.isEmpty()` lead to a NPE when registering a booking on a new session.

So I was wondering if it was possible for a Map to be non-null with no value in it (obviously, yes, but I'm also asking myself how) and how come it didn't return to null after it was completely emptied ?

And although I get that it is null after a `new` statement how come it is after the `session.getAttribute()` call ? It seems obvious since there is no Map stored in session yet, but at the same time it seems weird since there was no `new` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
    if (bookings == null)
```

is true, than you don't have a map (that's **different from an empty map**).

If the `else` block is executed, it means a map is referenced. You know nothing about about the number of elements in the map. You probably want something like this:

```
if (bookings == null)
{
     bookings= new HashMap<Integer, Booking>();
     identificator = 1;
} else if (bookings.isEmpty())
{
     identificator = 1;
}
else
{
     identificator = Collections.max(bookings.keySet()) + 1;
}
```

To answer this question:

> how come it didn't return to null after it was completely emptied ?

Look at this code:

```
Map<Integer, Booking> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I never entered any key/value pairs into the map, so it's empty. That's the same state as if I had put some key/value pairs into it, and then removed them again. The `map` is empty, but there is no reason for it to be `null`. If it were `null` we couldn't add anything again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` can be `null` (if not initialized) or empty (if initialized but no object was entered).
Removing object from map returns it to "empty" state (and **not** `null`).

`new` statement allocates memory for the object, and create it as an empty `HashMap` (and **not** null)

Answer (score 1):

Being *null* and being *empty* are completely different concepts. When a variable (reference type) is null, it point to nowhere. You have no `HashMap` at all. You just have an empty *pointer* (not an empty `HashMap`). You create a new `HashMap` using `bookings = new HashMap<Integer, Booking>()`. After that you have an *empty* `HashMap`. You acutally have a `HashMap`, but there is nothing inside it.

Also when you remove all the elements from the `HashMap`, it becomes *empty*, not *null*. To make it `null`, you have to explicitly do that:

```
bookings = null;
```